# What's the best way to write a OCaml parser in scala/java?

Tags: java, scala, parsing, ocaml, parser-generator

So I started to write a parser for OCaml in Scala with the Scala CombinatorParser,
but I get the feeling that this is not the right tool for the job.
Especially getting the precedences and associativity of operators and non-closed constructions right can be challenging. 
So my question is: Whats the best way to for such a real world parser like one for OCaml?
I looked into parser generators like ANTLR, but there are numerous and I have no idea which one would actually make the job easier.

Comment: Maybe take a look at a real world project, like the scala compiler itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look at [JavaCC](https://javacc.java.net/) generator. I find it quite useful to make DSL parsers. I guess it's a good candidate for parsing "real" languages too.

Answer (score 2):

OCaml parser is implemented in pretty straightforward lex+yacc. Therefore, the easiest way is to port the rules using the equivalent lex+yacc toolset in your language.

I do not mean converting OCaml parsing rules in LL(k) (i.e. Parsec) is completely impossible. Actually it is not very difficult if you write an automatic conversion tool: see my blog entry about it http://camlspotter.blogspot.sg/2011/05/planck-small-parser-combinator-library.html But, with human hands, it is an almost impossible task to do correctly in short time.

-edit-

On the second thought, the easiest way, if you are not a Scala/Java purist, is to use the original OCaml parser and write some OCaml code to output its AST to something easy to parse for any other languages, for example, S-exp.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check out [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/).  For small DSLs I found it very usable.  I assume it can handle complex languages as well.